# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[avgGpa]()
RETURNS decimal(3,2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CalcGPA decimal(10,2)
    DECLARE @CalcGPA2 decimal(3,2)

    SELECT @CalcGPA = SUM(cast(GPA AS decimal(10,2))) from dbo.Students
    SELECT @CalcGPA2 = cast(ROUND((@CalcGPA / 1000),2) AS decimal(3,2))

    RETURN @CalcGPA2
END
```

Comment: (1) why are you doing this in a function? (2) why are you storing GPA as a string? (3) [why are you asking the same question multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484825/msg-8115-arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-numeric-to-data-type-numeric-and)?

Comment: The duplicate question this links back to has been removed. Looks like  over zealous moderation?

Answer (score 1):

Give a bigger precision value.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[avgGpa]()    
RETURNS decimal(15,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised by conversion of a value with precision bigger than precision to that the value is converted.

Here is an example that reproduce the error:

```
   declare @d10 decimal(10,2)=12345678.12

   select CAST(@d10 as decimal(3,2))
```